# XE4 Firemonkey OLE typecast error (fetching win MAC Address)

Tags: delphi, com, firemonkey, ole, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4.

I'm porting a piece of code that compiles are runs under vcl (using ActiveX, vcl.oleauto) to a firemonkey friendly version.

It throws a Invalid typecast error. Anyone know what's different between the vcl units and these?

Thanks

John.

```
uses

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Win.ComObj,
  Winapi.ole2,
{$ENDIF}

SysUtils;


function GetfirstMacAddress : String;
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

begin
  Result := '';
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Description,MACAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);

  oEnum         := (IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum)) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.MACAddress) then
      begin
        Result := (FWbemObject.MACAddress);
        exit;
      end;
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not compile anywhere. Neither VCL nor FMX. So, this issue not related to FMX at all. Perhaps an earlier version did, but not the code here.

I think that @TLama is on the right track with your uses clauses. You need to the `IEnumVARIANT` from the `ActiveX` unit rather than the one from `Ole2`. The problem with the `IEnumVARIANT` in `Ole2` is that it is missing its `GUID` which means the `as` cast fails. And the `IUnknown` in `Ole2` is a class which is plain weird. And the `IEnumVARIANT._Next` in `Ole2` uses a signed integer for the `var` parameter, also weird. So, `Ole2` appears to be bad news!

Also, you were missing the `Variants` unit which is needed for `VarIsNull`.

This version of your code runs successfully:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Variants,
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  System.Win.ComObj;

function GetFirstMacAddress : String;
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

begin
  Result := '';
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Description,MACAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);

  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.MACAddress) then
      begin
        Result := (FWbemObject.MACAddress);
        exit;
      end;
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  Writeln(GetFirstMacAddress);
  Readln;
end.
```

This is probably right back to where you started! You don't want to use `ActiveX` in you FMX code. But `Ole2` is no good either. All you need to do is make a local declaration of `IEnumVARIANT` in your code. There's no need to take the whole of the `ActiveX` unit.

So start from the code above. Remove the `ActiveX` unit. And supply the good declaration of `IEnumVARAINT` copied from the `ActiveX` unit's source.

---

FWIW, I would not solve this problem with WMI. It is very heavyweight and just not needed for the task at hand.

Here's how I would obtain the MAC address of the local network interface:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.WinSock;

type
  TMacAddress = array [0..5] of Byte;

function SendARP(DestIP, SrcIP: ULONG; pMacAddr: Pointer; var PhyAddrLen: ULONG): DWORD; stdcall; external 'Iphlpapi.dll';

procedure InitializeWinSock;
var
  wsaData: TWSADATA;
begin
  Win32Check(Winapi.WinSock.WSAStartup($0202, wsaData)=0);
end;

procedure FinalizeWinSock;
begin
  Winapi.WinSock.WSACleanup;
end;

function inet_addr(const IPAddress: string): ULONG;
begin
  Result := ULONG(Winapi.WinSock.inet_addr(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IPAddress))));
end;

function GetMacAddress(const IPAddress: string): TMacAddress;
var
  MaxMacAddrLen: ULONG;
begin
  MaxMacAddrLen := SizeOf(Result);
  if SendARP(inet_addr(IPAddress), 0, @Result, MaxMacAddrLen)<>NO_ERROR then begin
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Unable to do SendARP on address: ''%s''', [IPAddress]);
  end;
end;

var
  i: Integer;
  mac: TMacAddress;

begin
  InitializeWinSock;
  mac := GetMacAddress('localhost');
  for i := low(mac) to high(mac) do
  begin
    Write(IntToHex(mac[i], 2));
    if i<high(mac) then
      Write(':');
  end;
  Writeln;
  FinalizeWinSock;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for that, its even lighter weight than the previous version.